# Unwanted extra space on body of PWA website

Tags: javascript, android, css, progressive-web-apps

I already tried a few approaches (with CSS) to solve this but it confuses me.

I made this small Schedule application for me and other parents of the class my 7-years-old is in. But it's showing this bottom extra space on the application on Android phones, probably because of the system's bottom bar...

[image]

The page is here: https://afonsofg.github.io/turma2g/ and the code repo here: https://github.com/AfonsoFG/turma2g

Can anyone help with hints on how can I tackle this?

Comment: Add `height:100vh` to `.container`. That should work.

Comment: I think I already tried that one! But will give it a go again! Thanks